# Seperable convolution using 1D FFT vs 2D FFT

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, fft, convolution

I am trying to use MATLAB to convolve an image with a Gaussian filter using two methods: separable convolution using the 1D FFT and non-separable convolution using the 2D FFT. I'm expecting the separable convolution to be faster.  However, it is not for small images, but for larger ones where the 2D is faster.  I'm not sure if it's a problem with my implementation or if it's because I don't have the concept quite right.

Here is my code:

```
img1 = randi([1,256],128,128);    

% Create a Gaassian filter
rf1 = fspecial('gaussian', [1 128], 1.0);
cf1 = transpose(rf1);
gf1 = cf1 * rf1;    

rc1 = round(conv2(img1, gf1, 'same'));
rc1 = fft2dconv(img1, gf1);
rc2 = fft1dconv(img1, rf1, cf1);


function o = fft1dconv(img, rowf, colf)

% Zero-Pad
imgsize = size(img);
rsize = size(rowf);
csize = size(colf);

img = padarray(img, [imgsize(1)/2, imgsize(2)/2]);
rowf = padarray(rowf, [2*imgsize(1)-rsize(1), 2*imgsize(2)-rsize(2)], 'post');
colf = padarray(colf, [2*imgsize(1)-csize(1), 2*imgsize(2)-csize(2)], 'post');


% Seperable convolution using 1D FFT
tic;
result = fft(transpose(fft(img))) .* fft(transpose(fft(colf)));
result = result .* fft(transpose(fft(rowf)));
o = transpose(round(real(ifft2(result))));
toc;


% Remove Pad
o = o(imgsize(1)+1:2*imgsize(1),imgsize(2)+1:2*imgsize(2));

end


function o = fft2dconv(img, filter)

%zero-pad
imgsize = size(img);
fsize = size(filter);

img = padarray(img, [imgsize(1)/2, imgsize(2)/2]);
filter = padarray(filter, [2*imgsize(1)-fsize(1), 2*imgsize(2)-fsize(2)], 'post');

% Non-Seperable convolution using 2D FFT
tic;
o = round(real(ifft2(fft2(img) .* fft2(filter))));
toc;

% Remove Pad
o = o(imgsize(1)+1:2*imgsize(1),imgsize(2)+1:2*imgsize(2));

end
```

And the timing results which are:

```
Elapsed time is 0.003315 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.004369 seconds.
```

For a 4 x 4 image, the separable method is much faster, but for larger images.  This is not the case and I'm not sure why. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just some guesses. (I don't know enough to verify any of these claims.) MATLAB's `fft2` also performs a separability check (and in fact, a SVD  low-rank approximation as well). Internally, `fft2` uses either ATLAS or FFTW, both of which are reputedly the fastest FFT implementations commercially available. (Some older versions used IPP.) Finally, the C implementation used inside MATLAB (when interfacing with ATLAS and FFTW) do not need to bother with performing the transposition - it just "tells" the underlying library to read the array in the transposed way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you [profile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) your code to see what is going on. It could be some other operations that you're doing instead of the core FFT calculations themselves.

Go into MATLAB and type in `profile viewer`. Once you do that, run your command in that window and let it finish. Once it finishes, it will identify the intensive parts of your code and you can figure out how to optimize it from there. You are right in saying that separable filters are faster.

Comment: @user115188 Woah! A ghost from the past! Did you end up figuring out why the timing was off?